# Why is 'god' a concept in Frege's objection on the ontological argument?

Tags: ontology, frege

As Frege states on "Function and Concept", a *concept* is a function which value is always a truth value, while an object is all that is not a function and therefore has no empty place (hopefully, I'm translating this the right way).

As I understand, '*Socrates*' is an object because it refers to the one Socrates, while 'cat' is a concept because we can talk about both a '*blue cat*' and a '*green cat*' (therefore, '*cat*' is a class/category of objects). I also understand that Frege's objection rests in the fact that '*god*' is a concept. This last part I do not understand.

Is Frege saying that '*god*' is a category, the same as '*cat*'? Doesn't the original argument refer to the one christian god?

Comment: What are you referring to exactly when you say "Frege's objection on the ontological argument"? Are you referring to this remark by Frege: "Because
 existence is a property of concepts the ontological argument for the
 existence of God breaks down"?

Comment: The issue is that the ontological argument is based on the assumption that existence is a property and the "definition" of God is such that his essence "includes" *existence*. According to Frege this "definition" is wrong because the existence is not a property of a concept that can be predicated of the objects falling under that concept. To say that a triangle exists means to say that the concept *triangle* is instantiated, i.e. that there are objects that are triangular. Thus, existence cannot be "verified" a priori, from the properties of the concept alone.

Comment: But yes, Frege is considering the *concept* "god" and see [Ontological arguments](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/): "St. Anselm claims to derive the existence of God from the concept of *a being than which no greater can be conceived*."

Comment: See [Frege and Russell: Existence is not a Property of Individuals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/#FreRusExiNotProInd)